# Azure Devops: CFD widget getting an error in the web interface after API call is made

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've been writing some Python code to programatically update the CFD widget settings, to display data for the last 14, 15, 16 days and so on.
But, as I was testing the [API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/dashboard/widgets/update-widget?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP) to update widgets, the web interface throws me an error:

```
TypeError: e.split is not a function
```

However, the API request I made got a successful return.
Here's the code:

```
import fazer_requisicoes
import json
import base64
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pprint import pp

load_dotenv()

token_do_azure = os.environ['AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT']

pat_encoded = base64.b64encode((":" + token_do_azure).encode()).decode()
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Basic {pat_encoded}'
}

settings_dict = {
    "chartDataSettings": {
        "timePeriod": {
            "settings": 16
        }
    }
}

def atualizar_cfd():
    organization = 'dummy'
    project = 'dummy'
    team = 'dummy'
    dashboard_id = 'dummy'
    widget_id = 'dummy'
    url = f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboard_id}/widgets/{widget_id}?api-version=7.2-preview.2'
    get_req = fazer_requisicoes.fazer_requisicoes("GET", url, headers)
    get_req_text = json.loads(get_req.text)
    # Assuming the ETag is in the body, otherwise look for it in the headers
    current_etag_widget = get_req_text['eTag']
    current_etag_dashboard = get_req_text['dashboard']['eTag']
    pp(current_etag_widget)
    pp(current_etag_dashboard)
    url = f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboard_id}/widgets/{widget_id}?api-version=7.2-preview.2'
    req_body = {
        "id": widget_id,
        "name": "Cumulative Flow Diagram (CFD)",
        "eTag": f'{current_etag_widget}',
        'position': {'row': 4, 'column': 5},
        "size": {
            "rowSpan": 2, "columnSpan": 3
        },
        'settings': settings_dict,
        "settingsVersion":
        {
            "major": 1,
            "minor": 0,
            "patch": 0
        },
        "contributionId": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.Microsoft.VisualStudioOnline.Dashboards.CumulativeFlowDiagramWidget",
        'dashboard': {'position': -1,
                      'eTag': f'{current_etag_dashboard}',
                      'modifiedDate': '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
                      'lastAccessedDate': '0001-01-01T00:00:00'},
    }
    req = fazer_requisicoes.fazer_requisicoes("PATCH", url, headers, req_body)
    req_text = json.loads(req.text)
    req_response = json.dumps(req_text)
    pp(req_response)


def main():
    atualizar_cfd()


main()
```

Here's the 'fazer_requisicoes function:

```
import requests
import time
import urllib3
from requests.exceptions import JSONDecodeError
from pprint import pprint

urllib3.disable_warnings()

session = requests.Session()

contador_timeout = 0
contador_SSL = 0

def fazer_requisicoes(metodo, url, headers, request_body=None):
    global contador_timeout
    global contador_SSL

    while True:
        try:
            if metodo in ['GET', 'DELETE']:
                req = session.request(metodo, url, headers=headers, verify=False)
            else:
                req = session.request(metodo, url, headers=headers, json=request_body, verify=False)
                try:
                    req.json()
                except JSONDecodeError:
                    print(f'{req.status_code}\n')
                    pprint(req.text)
                    print(f"Resposta inválida recebida. Tentando novamente...")
                    time.sleep(10)
                    continue 
            return req
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as e:
            contador_timeout += 1
            print(f"Erro de timeout número {contador_timeout}. Tentando novamente...")
            time.sleep(10)
        except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
            contador_SSL += 1
            print(f"Erro de SSL número {contador_SSL}. Tentando novamente...")
            time.sleep(10)
```

Can I fix it? If yes, how?

I've tried to use multilinein the settings, but it throwed another error in the web interface, a SyntaxError.

Comment: Did you try directly call the same REST API using Postman, PowerShell or Bash? Does the same error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue may be related to the following things:

1. The value of "**`settings`**" object is a json string in which the all the double quotes (**`"`**) are escaped by slash (**`\`**). When passing to the **`PATCH`** API call, also should use the escaped json string.
2. When updating the value of "**`settings`**" object, it seems needs to pass the whole escaped json string with the updated part instead of only the updated part to the **`PATCH`** API call.

Below is a Python sample I attempt on my side. It can work well to update the settings of CFD Widget without any error. You can reference it to update your Python script.

```
# coding=utf-8

import os
import json
import base64
import requests

organization = '{organization}'
project = '{project}'
team = '{team}'
dashboardId = '{dashboardId}'
widgetId = '{widgetId}'

ado_pat = os.environ['AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT']
b64token = base64.b64encode((":" + ado_pat).encode()).decode()

url = f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboardId}/widgets/{widgetId}?api-version=7.2-preview.2'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Basic {b64token}'
}

session = requests.Session()

print("-------------------- CFD Widget befor updating --------------------")
response_get = session.request('GET', url, headers=headers, json=None)
json_object_get = json.loads(response_get.content)
json_format_get = json.dumps(json_object_get, indent=2)
print(json_format_get)

print("-------------------- Updating CFD Widget --------------------")
body_patch = json_object_get

print("The settings before updating is:")
settings = body_patch["settings"]
json_object_settings = json.loads(settings)
json_format_settings = json.dumps(json_object_settings, indent=2)
print(json_format_settings)

print("Update the settings to:")
json_object_settings["chartDataSettings"]["timePeriod"]["settings"] = 20
json_format_settings_updated = json.dumps(json_object_settings, indent=2)
print(json_format_settings_updated)

print("-------------------- CFD Widget after updating --------------------")
body_patch["settings"] = json.dumps(json_object_settings).replace('"', '\"')
response_patch = session.request('PATCH', url, headers=headers, json=body_patch)
json_object_patch = json.loads(response_patch.content)
json_format_patch = json.dumps(json_object_patch, indent=2)
print(json_format_patch)
```